# How to access the folder path in web config using c#

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0

How can i access the folder path from web.config using c# code.
here is a sample code.

how to place this path in web config `C:\\whatever\\Data\\sample.xml`

i have to read this path from web config.

```
string folderpath = ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["path"].ToString();

using (XmlWriter xw = XmlWriter.Create(folderpath, new XmlWriterSettings { Indent = false }))
```

please help.....

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here is some sample code that should help you

This goes into your web.config.

```
<configuration>
    <appSettings>
        <add key="myFilePath" value="C:\\whatever\\Data\\sample.xml"/>
    </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

And this is how you read it:

```
path = System.Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["myFilePath"].ToString();
```

Answer (score 1):

Config file.

```
 <configuration>
      <appSettings>
        <add key="path" value="c:\dev"/>
      </appSettings>
    </configuration>
```

code to access it.

```
 string path = System.Configuration.ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["path"].ToString();
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you create a `SettingsManager` class, which has two methods:

```
public class SettingsManager
{
    public string Get(string key) 
    {
       // Reading settings from anywhere, in your case from web.config;
    }

    public string Save(string key, string value)
    {
       // Saving settings in a storage, here in web.config; 
    }
}
```

Then to read from web.config, simply use `WebConfigurationManager` using:

```
return WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings[key];
```