# Trouble accessing folder path from web config file

Tags: c#, xml

I was trying to use the solution found in this post:
[How to access the folder path in web config using c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10827870/how-to-access-the-folder-path-in-web-config-using-c-sharp) 
but I get a null reference exception (System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection.this[string].get returned null)?

I have this in my web config file (it's inside the configuration like shown in the post linked above):

```
<appSettings>
     <add key="SessionTest" value="C:\\Settings\\XmlDir\\Session\\20180824.xml"/>
</appSettings>
```

and retrieve it like so:

```
string path = System.Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SessionTest"].ToString();
```

Is there something simple that I'm missing here? The file exists in the folder (and I copied the path from the file explorer, so I'm having trouble understanding what is causing the null exception >.<")

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: That looks right.  Here is an example that I use.  Does the path exist? <add key="resultsFile" value="C:\\Test\\kiosk\\Logs\\kiosk_results.txt"/>

Comment: XML does not use backslash escaping.  You should only use a single backslash.

Comment: If it's a web.config app setting you're after I'd use `System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SessionTest"]`

Comment: What Ryan Searle said...that is prob what you want.

Comment: Hey everyone, thanks for the suggestions! I tried both SLaks and Ryan's solutions (together and individually), but I'm still getting the null exception :( 
Also, when I hardcode the path, I am able to retrieve the file so to the best of my knowledge the path does exist.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I'm aware this is the standard way to access `web.config` `<appSettings>`

```
System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SessionTest"]
```

Answer (score 0):

There was a second web config file that I wasn't aware of (I'm working on an old project so I didn't realize the first team that wrote this had added one to the folder I was working in, which in hindsight is probably a little strange)

When I added it to the web config file that is associated with the entire solution and not the one inside the folder I was working in, I was able to retrieve the value successfully! 
I want to also note I included SLaks suggestion from the comment he made (which is not to say it doesn't work with the double slashes, but I didn't include them when I found success so I can't confirm that).